# calling a wcf/soap method as an http get

Tags: wcf, rest, fiddler

Is there any way to enforce that a method call in soap based wcf is called as an HTTP get? I'm not sure if this would be handled on the client or server side. We wanted to have the wcf call process as a get vs. post for cacheability, etc.

I'm also not sure how to monitor a wcf service to determine if calls are doing gets or posts (or if it always does one or the other). Can I use fiddler for this?

I would imagine I could use a restful wcf service to wrap the call, but I wasn't sure if there was a way to do it straight in a soap based service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the box WCF functionality does not support SOAP HTTP GET. But WCF is extensible so you can try to develop custom binding (with cutom channel or behavior) supporting this feature.

Caching is supported in WCF 4 REST services. REST services allow all basic HTTP methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Fiddler to monitor the gets and posts.

Check out this [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/817bfbd7-82ef-4210-aa44-ac076540a540) about calling a WCF service with an HTTP GET.